# Avoir et être au passé composé

Tags: grammaire, sens, participe-passé, passé-composé, passif

« Je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir cette occasion qui m'est offerte aujourd'hui. » (Je m’aperçois qu’on va pas utiliser « qui m’a offert(e) »)

Par contre → Elle m’a eue.
                         Les fleurs, je les ai cueillies.

Pourquoi on utilise *être* avec offrir ?

Answer (score 10):

***L'occasion m'est offerte*** n'est pas au passé composé c'est une phrase au **présent de l'indicatif**, à la **voix passive**, dans laquelle l'agent n'est pas exprimé.

À la voix active la phrase serait :

- je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir l'occasion qu'on m'offre aujourd'hui.
  ou :
- je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir l'occasion que vous m'offrez aujourd'hui.
  si celui qui offre est la personne à laquelle on s'adresse.

Si on ne veut pas nommer la personne qui fait l'action (« l'agent » : *on*, *vous*), on met la phrase à la voix passive :

- je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir cette occasion qui m'est offerte.

Si l'action était au passé composé les deux phrases seraient :

- Voix active :

  - je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir cette occasion qu'on m'a offerte.
- Voix passive :

  - je vous remercie de me permettre de saisir cette occasion qui m'a été offerte.
    Cette dernière phrase est au passé composé,c'est le verbe être qui est conjugué au passé composé (et donc avec l'auxiliaire avoir) et qui est suivi du participe passé du verbe « offrir ».

Les deux phrases : « Elle m’a eue. » et « Les fleurs, je les ai cueillies. » sont toutes les deux au passé composé à la voix active. À la voix passive on aurait :

- les fleurs ont été cueillies.
- j'ai été eu. (tournure familière).

Comment: Merci beaucoup 

Comment: @user16887 Pas de problème, jespère que c'était clair. Si la réponse t'a aidé tu peux aussi [l'accepter](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour).